# IOS CoreLocation stopped working after Xcode 9 upgrade

Tags: ios, xcode, core-location, ios11

I'm learning Swift and IOS programming. I had this skeleton code working fine before upgrading to Xcode 9 and the IOS 11 simulator, but now it doesn't work at all and I'm at a loss. I've searched for whatever might have changed but haven't come up with anything. I know it's something simple.

In the app's plist file I set the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key so it's not complaining about asking permission from the user. The app builds fine and runs on the simulator but it never prints any location information and doesn't give any error. In the simulator I went to Debug->Location and set a lat/long.

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

var yourLongitude: Double = 0.0

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var manager: CLLocationManager!
    var location: CLLocation!

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        // Configure interface objects here.
        self.manager = CLLocationManager()
        self.manager.delegate = self;
        self.manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        self.manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        //NSLog("Here")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        NSLog("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
        yourLongitude = locValue.longitude
        printLongitude(yourLongitude)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        NSLog("Error with geolocation " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func printLongitude(_ longitude: Double) {
        var longitudeForLabel: String?
        if (longitude < 0) {
            longitudeForLabel = String(format: "%.03f", abs(longitude)) + "°W"
        } else {
            longitudeForLabel = String(format: "%.03f", longitude) + "°E"
        }
        LongitudeLabel.setText(longitudeForLabel!)
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        //NSLog("Here")
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        NSLog("app in foreground")
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could describe what you mean with "but now it doesn't work at all". Can you compile it? If not, what error do you see? What do you expect from it when you say "it worked before".

Comment: Thanks- I edited my question. It still compiles fine but doesn't print any location information.

Comment: Strange, it works fine on a real device. No matter what I try in the simulator the location service never runs or asks the user for permission or anything.